# A simple proof for angle inequality in inner product spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am looking for a smiple proof for the following fact:
Let $u,v,w$ be vectors in an inner product space $V$.
Then it holds:

$\theta (u, v)≤\theta(u, w) + \theta(w, v)$

(Of course if they are all in a single plane and $w$ is "between" $u,v$ there is an equality).

So far I have only found proofs which seem a bit too complicated then necessary. (For instance [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.2800.pdf)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be thought of as the triangle inequality applied to a "geodesic" metric on the sphere.  In particular: given unit-vectors $u$ and $v$, $\theta(u,v)$ is the minimal distance from $u$ to $v$ along a curve on the surface of the unit sphere.

If we define the angle via this minimum (or show that the angle is equal to this minimum), then of course the inequality holds: the minimum length of all arcs from $u$ to $v$ is certainly at most the minimum length of all arcs from $u$ to $v$ that pass through $w$.

I would like to think that establishing the equivalence of these notions would be a routine application of the calculus of variations.  Then again, I have not at all tried this for myself.  I also have no idea whether this idea would extend to infinite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @AsafSchachar thanks for accepting!  So was this useful, then?

Comment: Yes, your solution is very elegant. Thanks. By the way, I think it is unnecessary to consider the infinite dimensional case since $sp\{v,w,u\}$ is 3-dimensional, so we can restrict our discussion to 3 dimensional subspaces.

Comment: You're welcome. And that's a good point about the restriction to the span.  I suppose it's reasonable to assume that it's impossible to take a "shortcut" that leaves this sphere.